# ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext;

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, spring-cloud-feign

I am working on a project that is spring boot and using feign client.
Main Application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class ABCApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ABCApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application is deployed in openshift and it is working fine.
I added a filter in spring boot service as below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.google.common.net.HttpHeaders;

@Component
public class CheckFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String CHECK_DOMAIN = "check.com";

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String referer = httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(referer) && referer.indexOf(CHECK_DOMAIN) >= 0) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        filterConfig = null;
    }

}
```

I have experience in spring boot but new to feign client concept.
After adding above filter and deployed application in openshift, pods are crashing and continously restarting with below error log.

```
INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO 1 --- [           main] com.abc.ms.ABCApplication       : Started ABCApplication in 12.568 seconds (JVM running for 13.381)
INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 27 ms
INFO 1 --- [       Thread-5] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@56f4468b: startup date [Thu Sep 16 15:36:42 GMT 2021]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@61e4705b
INFO 1 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
INFO 1 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
INFO 1 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
INFO 1 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
WARN 1 --- [       Thread-5] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
INFO 1 --- [       Thread-5] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
```

Anybody has knowledge on spring boot or feign client, please answer the issue.

Comment: Please let me know if more information is required to answer the question

Comment: afaik open shift uses a URL to poll if the application is up, your filter blocks that URL and thus after a certain timeframe things will be shutdown (or rather shot down) and restart. Basically your filter is to broad.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. It helped a lot.